# Rails- i can't hide entries records in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, record

sorry but i'm starting with Ruby on rails.the solution will surely seem simple.
i have a ***food/index*** view with this line

```
  <%= @foods.each do |food| %>
  <%= food.title %>
    <%= food.description%>
    <%= food.price %>
    <a href="/">home</a>
    <%end%>
```

foods_controller

```
  def index
@foods = Food.all
end
```

it works but ,i have a list of food with the home link for each but i have  all my array foods params at the bottom  ,with id or created at for example.
i would like to hide this.
could you help me,please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 <%= @foods.each do |food| %>
```

to

```
 <% @foods.each do |food| %>
```

You just want to start a bit of ruby code in this bit, you don't want to actually 'print' the results to your view yet.

Comment: wow I tried a lot of code in my controller and in my view, but it was easier than I thought.Thanks for your help.